# Can't install WFFM on Sitecore 8.2 update 1

Tags: wffm

I am trying to install Web Form for marketers (Web Forms for Marketers 8.2 rev. 161129 NOT SC PACKAGE) on my sitecore 8.2 update 1 instance. It's not installing, neither throwing any error or nothing logging in logs. I checked windows event viewer but there is nothing related to wffm. Any clue what could be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Web Forms for Marketers 8.2 rev. 161129 NOT SC PACKAGE** is not a Sitecore Package like its name say. This zip file contains 3 other zip file: one for CM,one for Content Delivery and one for Reporting.  Please unzip this file and install packages for CM or for other servers. Please see below picture:

[image]